# jest@23.1.0 collectCoverageFrom not picking the files outside root directory

Tags: jestjs, babel-jest, test-coverage

When I run code coverage, code inside the root directory containing jest config works perfectly but for the code outside the root directory test cases passes but in the coverage report it shows zero percentage for all the test files outside the root directory.

***jest.config.js*** file is inside explorebook folder.

### directory structure:

```
|---core
|   |--components
|      |--test
|   |--jest.setup.suites.js
|---explorebook
|    |--components
|    |  |--test
|    |--package.json
|    |--jest.config.js
|    |--jest.setup.suites.js
|---framework    
|     |--commons
|        |--test
|     |--jest.setup.suites.js 
|
```

**jest.config.js**

```
const TEST_FILES_REGEX = '(/test/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.js$';

module.exports = {
    verbose: false,
    roots: [
        '<rootDir>/',
        '<rootDir>/../core/',
        '<rootDir>/../framework/commons/'
    ],
    collectCoverage: true,
    collectCoverageFrom: [
         'components/**/*.js',
         '<rootDir>/../core/components/**/*.js'
         '<rootDir>/../framework/commons/*.js'
    ],
    coverageDirectory: 'reports/coverage',
    coverageReporters: [
        'lcov',
        'text'
    ],
   setupFiles: [ '<rootDir>/jest.setup.suites.js', 
          '<rootDir>/../core/jest.setup.suites.js', 
          '<rootDir>/../framework/jest.setup.suites.js' ],
   setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: path.join(__dirname, 'jest.setup.tests.js'),
   testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
   testRegex: TEST_FILES_REGEX

};
```

[coverage report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP66C.jpg)

Even if all the outside the rootDir passes, report does not show that.

I would expect the coverage values for files outside also to be correct in the report.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 8):

Jest will retrofit code coverage only on **files inside the project's `rootDir`** ([source](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#collectcoveragefrom-array)). In your setup, this will be the `explorebook` folder.

To also run coverage on files in a different folder than the one containing `jest.config.js`, I suggest setting `[rootDir]` ([source](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#rootdir-string)) to your project's root folder, and update any necessary paths:
**jest.config.js**

```
const TEST_FILES_REGEX = '(/test/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.js$';

module.exports = {
    verbose: false,
    rootDir: './../' // This should point to your project root folder
    collectCoverage: true,
    collectCoverageFrom: [
         '**/*.js',
    ],
    coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/explorebook/reports/coverage',
    coverageReporters: [
        'lcov',
        'text'
    ],
   setupFiles: [ '<rootDir>/explorebook/jest.setup.suites.js', 
          '<rootDir>/core/jest.setup.suites.js', 
          '<rootDir>/framework/jest.setup.suites.js' ],
   setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: path.join(__dirname, 'jest.setup.tests.js'),
   testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
   testRegex: TEST_FILES_REGEX

};
```

Comment: Why can't other answers be as clear and direct as this.
Spent hours on this issue only to realize I had the wrong path in `--collectCoverageFrom`, that is I was checking my test files for coverage ... oops.

Thank you for this!